# How to set the columns of the kendo angular 2 grid and its cell templates in the code

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-grid

I want to manage the grid column settings like the old version of angular, in the code. Is this feature present?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code to manage your column definitions And use *ngFor/ngIf in template to map your columns to kendo grid's.